# Problems with cocos2d schedule method selectors

Tags: objective-c, events, cocos2d-iphone, selector, scheduler

I have the following code (that should be correct):

```
- (void) loadIntro:(ccTime)unused {
    [[GameManager sharedGameManager] runWithSceneID:kIntroScene]; // fade to the intro screen
}


- (void) loadAppScreen {
    CCSprite *commodoreScreenLoaded = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"CommodoreLoadedApp.png"];
    useBackgroundImage(commodoreScreenLoaded);
    [self addChild:commodoreScreenLoaded];
}


- (void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    // location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    CGRect mySurface = (CGRectMake(100, 100, 320, 480));
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(mySurface, location)) {
        //[[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
        play(@"InsertGameCartridge.wav");

        [self removeChild:commodoreScreen cleanup:YES];
        [self loadAppScreen];
        [self schedule:@selector(loadIntro:) interval:2.5f]; // <-- Right here!
}
```

But when I run it, it logs a really weird error:

```
2012-07-29 12:21:41.186 Apocanaut[7299:707] *** Assertion failure in -[CCTimer initWithTarget:selector:interval:repeat:delay:],/Users/chris/src/Apps/Games/Apocanaut/Apocanaut/libs/cocos2d/CCScheduler.m:111

2012-07-29 12:21:41.190 Apocanaut[7299:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Signature not found for selector - does it have the following form? -(void) name: (ccTime) dt'
```

**EDIT**:

It seems to be coming from a method in the `GameManager` class, which I've implemented a scene called `runWithSceneID`:

```
- (void) runWithSceneID:(SceneTypes)sceneID {
    SceneTypes oldScene = currentScene;
    currentScene        = sceneID;
    id sceneToRun       = nil;

    switch (sceneID) {
        case kMenuScene:
            sceneToRun = [MenuScene node];
            break;

        case kCommodoreScene:
            sceneToRun = [CommodoreScene node];
            break;

        case kIntroScene:
            sceneToRun = [IntroScene node];
            break;

        default:
            CCLOG(@"No scene ID to load");
            return;
            break;
    }

    if (sceneToRun == nil) {
        currentScene = oldScene;
        return;
    }

    if ([[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] == nil) {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:sceneToRun];
    } else {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:
         [CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:kStandardTransitionDuration scene:sceneToRun]];
    }
}
```

Comment: What the ```loadAppScreen``` method does?

Comment: @YannickL. I've also added a new method explaining the GameManager method `runWithSceneID`, it seems to be the culprit.

Comment: It could be run. Have you tried to comment your ```[self schedule:@selector(loadIntro:) interval:2.5f];``` and call the method directly instead (```[self loadIntro:2.5f]```)?

Comment: @YannickL. I just tried it out, it gives the same error as the `@selector(...)` version. :(

Comment: It seems that your ```- (void)loadIntro:(ccTime)unused``` does not exists... So either your method does not exist into your object or your object is released before you call this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not certain why it makes a difference, but in certain cases this has solved some really opaque bugs of this nature for me. Declare your method in a private category as such (MPBattleSequencer is one of my scenes, use your own class):

```
@interface MPBattleSequencer (private)

// snip-x-snip

-(void) loadIntro:(ccTime)unused;

@end
```